# Make action available only for admin

Tags: magento2, admin, ajax, security, action

I added a button to admin order view which sends request to an url of an action controller (using ajax), and now I need to somehow make it available only for admin. What is the best solution for this problem? Also I can abandon ajax if there is a better option for the button.

Possible solution that occurred to me is to add something to header and then check it in the action function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AJAX controller should use admin router and that's it.

`app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="modulename" frontName="modulename">
            <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Your AJAX controller should be placed under `Controller/Adminhtml` folder, eg. `app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index` and it should extend `\Magento\Backend\App\Action`.

Then, use `$block->getUrl('modulename/index/index')` in your admin block and use generated URL for your AJAX.